# Flask secret key length

Tags: python, flask, secret-key

What is the maximum secret key size that can be used in python flask applications? All of the examples I've seen online, including http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions seem to recommend using 192 bit keys but I'm wondering if it's possible to use a 256 bit key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask employs `itsdangerous.Signer` to do session data signing, the key used in signing is not the one you provided with `SECRET_KEY` config option but [is derived](https://github.com/pallets/itsdangerous/blob/master/itsdangerous.py#L338-L371) with an [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF).

By default, Flask [uses HMAC-SHA1](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py#L304-L331) as HKDF algorithm, you only get 160-bits signing key, the length of `SECRET_KEY` makes no difference. In order to get 256 bits *session* signing key, you could extend `flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface`, change `digest_method` to SHA256, of course, you still need a lengthy random `SECRET_KEY` for enough entropy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have a 32 bytes secret key size.

But, from [Applied Criptography](http://[1]:%20https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/):

> Longer key lengths are better, but only up to a point. AES will have
>   128-bit, 192-bit, and 256-bit key lengths. This is far longer than
>   needed for the foreseeable future. In fact, we cannot even imagine a
>   world where 256-bit brute force searches are possible. It requires
>   some fundamental breakthroughs in physics and our understanding of the
>   universe.

So following the docs: size of 24 bytes and generating it randomly you should be fine.

Also, take a look at [Is it possible to break a 128-bit key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376751/is-it-possible-to-break-a-128-bit-key). This will give you an ideia about how much time is need to break a 128 bit key.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can make the secret key as long as you want, but in the grand scheme, the security strength will be still subjective. Your app won't be much more secure than others'.

I would stick with the default recommended values. There must be reasons why they are recommended.